# How do I run a databricks notebook from a .py file in Azure?

Tags: python, testing, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to use pytest to test a series of notebooks another colleague wrote. I am able to handle most of it, however they call a base class/module developed within Azure Databricks.

This works when within notebooks:

```
%run ../dbx_class
dbx_class.some_function() # Runs as it is in memory
```

However when using dbutils I cannot seem to execute the code again

```
dbutils.notebook.run('../dbx_class',0) # Executes just fine
dbx_class.some_function() # NameError: name 'dbx_class' is not defined
```

After reading on the [Azure documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#dbutilsnotebook-api) it appears the notebook does not execute within the same memory space as what happens with the %run method.

How do I execute this appropriately? Is there a way to execute this in the current space from a .py file?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `%run` and `dbutils.notebook.run` - the former **evaluates**  code of the child notebook in the content of the parent notebook into the current context, so you can access functions & classes defined there.  The latter **executes** the given notebook as a separate task in its own context, so all definitions aren't imported...

P.S. I would recommend to switch to the use of [Python files](https://docs.databricks.com/files/workspace-modules.html), so you can import them as normal Python modules.

Comment: Hey Alex Ott, I've found a few of your posts in the past. I agree it would be good to move to .py files as we move forward; however the team I am working with is not yet inclined to do so.

Do you have any recommendations for evaluating a notebook within a .py file?

Comment: you need to use `%run` if you need to access the code/variables defined in that notebook

Comment: But that won't execute in a .py file, correct?

Comment: Not file, it should be notebook

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Is there any possible way to work around this?

Comment: Cant you run the .py file from a script of a notebook then? Just tangling around a bit.

Comment: @ZiyaMertKarakas that's a good question. I could, but it's my understanding of how pytest works that, once invoked, it executes items on it's own. So when it searches the folder for test_myStuff.py it doesn't have the other notebooks in memory.